# Error when exporting products: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool

Tags: magento2, export, magento2.4

I'm getting this error when trying to export products:

> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $publishers of Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool.

From exception.log

[2020-04-30 19:28:31] main.CRITICAL: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool {"report_id":"28a0645effcf33b263b1cc45ebf94987ba9754b7bcb411fbf478c2e235cb0068","exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException(code: 0): Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\PublisherPool at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:131)"} []

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Should be solved by enabling the following Magento modules:

Magento_MessageQueue

Magento_MysqlMq

(using MySQL instead of RabbitMQ for messages)

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_MysqlMq Magento_MessageQueue --clear-static-content
```

Comment: thanks its worked for me